# How can I simplify this Java code?

Tags: java

I am fairly new in Java and need to do some ugly if / else code.

```
if (st1 == 0 || st2 == 0 || st3 == 0) {
  if (st1 == 0) {
    return a;
  } else if (st2 == 0) {
    return b;
  } else {
    return c;
  }
}
```

But to me it seems like there should be some simpler way to do this kind of code.
(I know i could leave the outer if away, but it is for the purpose of showing the problem)

I hope somebody has an idea on how to beautify this code :)

Comment: The outer condition is mostly redundant. Just remove that, and replace the `else` with `else if (st3 == 0)`. And in fact the `else`s are then redundant too.

Comment: Remove the outer if statement. It‘s like saying a sentence twice. It’s unnecessary tiring and people already got it the first time.

Comment: What about using a ternary operator? `return st1 == 0 ? a : st2 == 0 ? b : st3 == 0 ? c : /* TODO: non equal 0. return what you want */;`

Comment: Incomplete. What is supposed to happen if none of them are zero?

Comment: @EJP execution continues to the following statement. This is clearly just part of a method, what with the lack of method and containing class declaration.

Comment: @JaredRummler Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @BeatzCraft I would advise against nested conditional expressions. They are not used very often, and so some people find them confusing to read, especially if you cram it all on a single line; and they are no more efficient at runtime. Unless you're developing code on a tiny screen, the extra vertical space taken by regular conditionals is worth using.

Comment: @AndyTurner Which makes the question incomplete, and most of these comments incorrect, but I was asking the OP, and it is up to him to answer, in more detail than that. If the answer is to return `c` whatever the value of `st3`, most of the comments above are correct:if not, not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the outer condition, and remove unnecessary 'else':

```
if (st1 == 0) {
    return a;
}
if (st2 == 0) {
    return b;
}
if (st3 == 0) {
    return c;
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of youre code against using else if?

Comment: The advantage is less code that's easier to read - 'else' after 'return' is redundant since 'return' causes method execution to end.